# How to disable virtual products

Tags: virtual-products

We have several clients that keep forgetting to add a **weight** to their **simple** products and thus creating **virtual** products.

This creates problems later on in the checkout where there is no option to enter a shipping address nor to select a shipping method.

We keep telling them how to change them to simple products using the bulk editing, and how to add weight in the first place, but it is a recurring thing. Most of our clients have shops where they will never need virtual products anyway.

So my idea is to "disable" virtual products all together (I didn't find a way to do that yet).

Or maybe write an observer at "product save" that sets `weight` to an arbitrary value and `has_weight` to `1`, if there isn't anything set.

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

To remove *Virtual Product* from the **Add Product** options in the admin panel (assuming your clients create products through the admin panel)

Override the Adminhtml Block in your module by adding a preference in your di.xml

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product

and modify the method **_getAddProductButtonOptions** and add these lines to skip the **Virutal Product** to options

```
    /**
     * Retrieve options for 'Add Product' split button
     *
     * @return array
    */
    protected function _getAddProductButtonOptions()
    {
        $splitButtonOptions = [];
        $types = $this->_typeFactory->create()->getTypes();
        uasort(
            $types,
            function ($elementOne, $elementTwo) {
            return ($elementOne['sort_order'] < $elementTwo['sort_order']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        );

        foreach ($types as $typeId => $type) {

            // add these lines to skip adding virtual products to the 'Add Product' button options 
            if (stripos($typeId,'virtual') !== FALSE)  {
                continue;
            }

            $splitButtonOptions[$typeId] = [
                'label' => __($type['label']),
                'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getProductCreateUrl($typeId) . "')",
                'default' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::DEFAULT_TYPE == $typeId,
            ];
        }

             return $splitButtonOptions;
    }
```

> This is the recommended way to disable (not actually) the virtual
> product and not giving an option to your customers to add virutal
> products from the admin panel. This is much simpler and easier way than the other options available to get rid of Virtual Products in your magento2 store.
>
> make sure to compile your code after this   `bin/magento s:d:c`

Remember the **Vitual Product** is not completely disabled and still its possible to create Virtual Products through REST API / GraphQL routes.

In case, if you want to get rid of the virtual products all together then
override the `product_types.xml` in your module and remove the `Virtual Product <type>`.

Need to remove these lines

```
<type name="virtual" label="Virtual Product" modelInstance="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual" indexPriority="20" sortOrder="40">
        <indexerModel instance="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price\VirtualProductPrice" />
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="false"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because disabling the **Virtual** product type feature completely might pose a risk, I suggest setting the "product has weight" attribute to "yes" to force it to be a simple product.

Let's go! When you save a product or update product attributes it will call the `processProduct` method in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TypeTransitionManager` to set the product type. Since this is a public method, you can add a `before` plugin to force set `product_has_weight` to `1`.

Finally, your plugin class looks like the following:
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/ForceSetProductHasWeight.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TypeTransitionManager;

class ForceSetProductHasWeight
{
    /**
     * @param TypeTransitionManager $subject
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeProcessProduct(TypeTransitionManager $subject, Product $product): array
    {
       // Customization: Force set product has weight in case product has no weight
        // to prevent it set product type to virtual product
        if (!$product->getData('product_has_weight')) {
            $product->setData('product_has_weight', 1);
        }

        return [$product];
    }
}
```

The `di.xml` config should look like this:
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TypeTransitionManager">
        <plugin name="ForceSetProductHasWeight" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\ForceSetProductHasWeight"/>
    </type>
</config>
```